# Outlook VBA draft emails without "save changes" dialog

Tags: vba, mailitem

I use VBA to create new MailItem elements and move them to my inbox.
Since they are not sent they are handled as drafts from Outlook's perspective.
This means, when I open such an element I cannot close it without the annoying saving prompt.

[image: Do you want to save/discard prompt in German (sorry)]

Is there a way to work with unsent mail elements to keep track of things?
I could also send these elements to my own mail address but this would sometimes take a bit longer until it's received. So I'd prefer to just create them locally.

Answer (score 0):

With `.Close` you designate olDiscard, olPromptForSave or olSave.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.close(method)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub closeWithoutPromptToSave()

    Dim currItem As MailItem
    
    Set currItem = ActiveInspector.currentItem
    currItem.Close olSave
    
End Sub
```